# Determining values a & b from a given equation.

Tags: linear-algebra

A particles displacement (in meters) from the origin with respect to time (in seconds) is given by the following equation:

$ \frac{t^3}{3}$-$5t^2$+at+b

where 0<t<8

Given that the particle is initially at the origin and has a displacement of 27 meters at 3 seconds, determine the values of a & b.

*Edit

Started with substituting in the t = 3

$ \frac{3^3}{3}$-$5(3)^2$+a(3)+b = 27

And I could solve to get b = -3a+63

But upon substituting that back in to find a it ended with 27 = 27 thus a = 0

Not sure if where I went wrong or if I just missed something

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  An obvious place to start is to use the given information to get information on $a,b$.

Comment: Here's something to get you started: "Given that the particle is initially at the origin..." means that at time $t = 0$ (i.e. "initially"), the displacement $\frac{t^3}{3}-5t+at+b$ equals $0$. So, try substituting $t = 0$ into the expression (which again equals $0$ in that case) and see if you can find the value of $b$. Then, try something similar when $t = 3$, given the expression is $27$. This will give you $a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing fine! The reason you're getting a useless tautology like $27=27$ is that $b = -3a + 63$ is exactly what you got from the information that the displacement is $27$ when $t = 3$. The equation you got was equivalent, and so trying to use it with the same piece of information is only going to confirm what you've already shown to be true.

Remember the information $b = -3a + 63$, as it is just one piece of the puzzle. You need to use the other piece of the puzzle, which I mentioned in my comment above: the displacement is $0$ "initially", meaning that $t = 0$. So, this means that
$$\frac{0^3}{3} - 5(0)^2 + a(0) + b = 0.$$
From this you can hopefully see that $b = 0$. Substitute $b = 0$ into the equation you came up with to find $a$.